# My ASCII box is breaking after printing out 18 lines of it, external terminal in VS Code

Tags: python

I'm trying to make an inventory screen for my text-based RPG game (If you have a better site to do it on other than VS Code let me know) and I wanted to make a box to list everything, I got one but it doesn't complete it and messes up after 18 lines.

This is the code I tried:

```
    print("┼" + "─" * 208 + "┼", end="")
    for i in range(20):
        print("|" + " " * 208 + "|", end="")
    print("┼" + "─" * 208 + "┼")
```

And I'm using an external terminal on VS Code with python extensions.

Comment: The issue you're facing is likely due to the end="" argument in the print function inside the loop. This argument prevents the print function from moving to the next line after printing, causing all the lines to be printed on the same line.

To fix this, you should remove the end="" argument from the print function inside the loop.

Comment: Regarding your question about a better site or environment to code in other than VS Code: VS Code is a very popular and versatile code editor, and with the right extensions, it can be a powerful tool for Python development. If you're comfortable with it, I'd recommend sticking with it. However, if you're looking for an integrated development environment (IDE) specifically designed for Python, you might consider using PyCharm. It offers many features tailored for Python development, including debugging, code completion, and more.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it doesn't complete it and messes up after 18 lines"? Could you add a screenshot of the messed-up part?